# Могут ли слова "экстренный" и "чрезвычайный" использоваться в одном словосочетании?

Tags: словосочетания

Обеспечить исправность всего автотранспорта и спецтехники для бесперебойного ведения технологических процессов, а также резерв техники на случай непредвиденных чрезвычайных ситуаций.
В случае возникновения нештатных ситуаций, экстренных чрезвычайных ситуаций незамедлительно докладывать руководителю.

Comment: Если ответ решил проблему - можно отметить его галочкой (под нижним серым треугольником слева от ответа).

Answer (score 1):

Могут. **Чрезвычайной** ситуация (предусмотренная или непредвиденная) может быть по *тяжести последствий* в случае беспрепятственного развития, а **экстренной** - по *неотложности* разрешения. Пример: глобальное потепление (для тех, кто в него верит) - ситуация чрезвычайная, но не экстренная. То же с аварийным отключением блока электростанции: оно предусмотрено проектом и при неблагоприятных обстоятельствах может потребовать длительного планового ремонта (ситуация чрезвычайная по экономическим или даже социальным последствиям), с в то время как неотложные (=экстренные) меры, напр. с участием спасателей и т. п. могут не понадобиться.

Comment: Да ладно. Глобальное потепление - экстренная проблема. Постоянно говорят, что нужно срочно принимать меры, иначе будет поздно.

Comment: https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Чрезвычайная_ситуация Такие ситуации сами по себе экстренные, так как требуют срочного вмешательства.

Answer (score 0):

В вашем примере не могут. У слова "чрезвычайный" уже может быть значение "экстренный". Особенно это выражается при слове "ситуации".
[https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Чрезвычайная_ситуация](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D1%80%D0%B5%D0%B7%D0%B2%D1%8B%D1%87%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BD%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D1%81%D0%B8%D1%82%D1%83%D0%B0%D1%86%D0%B8%D1%8F)
Чрезвычайные ситуации сами по себе экстренные, так как требуют срочного вмешательства.

Толковый словарь:
чрезвычайный
Экстренный, вызванный исключительными обстоятельствами, не предусмотренный обычным ходом дел.
*Чрезвычайный суд.

Чрезвычайные меры.

Чрезвычайный съезд.

Чрезвычайная комиссия.

С чрезвычайными полномочиями отправиться куда-либо.

Чрезвычайное положение.

Чрезвычайные налоги.*

Но при значении чего-то срочного (экстренный) и необычного (чрезвычайный) — могут, но тогда их всё же лучше заменить на другие слова.

Comment: «... не предусмотренный обычным ходом дел.» Вы правильно заметили, и укр. и бел. тут нам в помощь: в них ЗВЫЧАЙНО = обычно. Чрезвычайно — за границами обычного, т.е. всего лишь — необычно. И значения "экстренности" в слове этом нет.

Comment: Я же с толкового словаря брал это всё. В некоторых словосочетаниях всё же прослеживается такое значение. Думаю, когда необычность требует срочного вмешательства.

Comment: @shampar Просто понял, что вопрос про конкретный пример, а не в общем. Возможно, так и есть. Но добавил про такое сочетание в общем.